# Best way to compare data elements using Fuzzy Match Algorithms

Tags: levenshtein-distance, hamming-distance, fuzzy-comparison

I am looking to compare two data elements or fields via Fuzzy Match Algorithm for Record Linkage in `C#`, and I want to determine which algorithm would be best for each comparison.

The fields I am looking to compare are:

- Last Name
- First Name
- Gender
- Birth Year
- Birth Month
- Birth Day
- SSN
- Member Number
- MRN
- Street Number
- Street Name
- Street Type
- Street Directional
- City
- State
- Zip
- Phone

The **Approximate String Matching Algorithms** (ASMs) I am utilizing currently are:

- Levenshtein Distance
- Hamming Distance
- Jaccard Distance
- Jaro Distance
- Jaro-Winkler Distance
- Longest Common Subsequence
- Longest Common Substring
- Overlap Coefficient
- Ratcliff-Obershelp Similarity
- Sorensen-Dice Distance
- Tanimoto Coefficient
- Damerau-Levenshtein Distance
- Wagner-Fisher Distance
- Soundex
- Metaphone 3
- NYSIIS

Firstly, I am comparing two fields such as `FirstName1` and `FirstName2` and seeing if they are an exact match.

For example, `FirstName1 = "Bob"` and `FirstName2 = "Bob"` will be an exact match so it will not move on to fuzzy-matching.

On the other hand `FirstName1 = "Jill"` and `FirstName2 = "Bob"` will move on to a fuzzy-comparison on the two fields.

I want to know if anyone knows what fuzzy-match algorithm is better to use on certain field comparisons and not others, vice versa.

Comment: This question serves as a nice list of string comparison algorithms!

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote some similar code for entity resolution. The key though is that *not all fields are created equal*. For example, you should **not** use ASMs on `SSN`- even one number/character being different is a totally different SSN and person.

Instead of fuzzy matching address components, I would try to resolve the addresses first and then do an exact match. For example, a good address resolution service will treat:

`Second Street NW` and `NW 2nd St`

as the same street even though they have very poor similarity by all those metrics.

Likewise, you can use Google's phone number parsing library (available for C#, Java, etc.) to format all phone numbers in a standard way and then do direct comparison.

I did use Jaro-Winkler to compare name components, but I did not research several of the metrics you have listed.

In short:

**Canonicalize and compare**

instead of fuzzy match.